# how many unread bytes left in a file?

Tags: python, file

I read periodically 16-bit frames from a file,
last frame I need to know if there are enough data and file is valid for my format.

```
f.read(16)
```

returns an empty string if there is no more data more or data if there is at least 1 byte.
How can I check how many unread bytes are left in a file?

Comment: Why not simply check the length of the string returned by `f.read(16)`?  If it is 16, fine, use it, if it is less than 16, there wasn't enough data left.

Comment: How about just getting the file size before reading it? : `os.path.getsize(filename)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that, you'd have to know the size of the file. Using the [file](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) object, you could do the following:

```
f.seek(0, 2)
file_size = f.tell()
```

The variable `file_size` will then contain the size of your file in bytes. While reading, simply do `f.tell() - file_size` to get the number of bytes remaining. So:

Comment: isn't it `file_size - f.tell()`?

Answer (score 3):

perhaps a little easiser to use..

```
def LengthOfFile(f):
    """ Get the length of the file for a regular file (not a device file)"""
    currentPos=f.tell()
    f.seek(0, 2)          # move to end of file
    length = f.tell()     # get current position
    f.seek(currentPos, 0) # go back to where we started
    return length

def BytesRemaining(f,f_len):
    """ Get number of bytes left to read, where f_len is the length of the file (probably from f_len=LengthOfFile(f) )"""
    currentPos=f.tell()
    return f_len-currentPos

def BytesRemainingAndSize(f):
    """ Get number of bytes left to read for a regular file (not a device file), returns a tuple of the bytes remaining and the total length of the file
        If your code is going to be doing this alot then use LengthOfFile and  BytesRemaining instead of this function
    """
    currentPos=f.tell()
    l=LengthOfFile(f)
    return l-currentPos,l


if __name__ == "__main__":
   f=open("aFile.data",'r')
   f_len=LengthOfFile(f)
   print "f_len=",f_len
   print "BytesRemaining=",BytesRemaining(f,f_len),"=",BytesRemainingAndSize(f)
   f.read(1000)
   print "BytesRemaining=",BytesRemaining(f,f_len),"=",BytesRemainingAndSize(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `seek(0, 2)` and `tell()`

```
BUFF = 16
f = open("someFile", "r")
x = 0
# move to end of file
f.seek(0, 2)

# get current position
eof = f.tell()  

# go back to start of file
f.seek(0, 0)

# some arbitrary loop
while x < 128:
    data = f.read(BUFF)
    x += len(data)

# print how many unread bytes left
unread = eof - x
print unread
```

[File Objects - Python Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html):

> - `seek(offset[, whence])` Set the file's current position, like stdio's fseek(). The whence argument is optional and defaults to 0
>     (absolute file positioning); other values are 1 (seek relative to the
>     current position) and 2 (**seek relative to the file's end**). There is no
>     return value. Note that if the file is opened for appending (mode 'a'
>     or 'a+'), any seek() operations will be undone at the next write. If
>     the file is only opened for writing in append mode (mode 'a'), this
>     method is essentially a no-op, but it remains useful for files opened
>     in append mode with reading enabled (mode 'a+'). If the file is opened
>     in text mode (without 'b'), only offsets returned by tell() are legal.
>     Use of other offsets causes undefined behavior. Note that not all file
>     objects are seekable.
> - `tell()` Return the file's current position, like stdio's ftell().